# Bi-directional reference

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an `Image` and `ImageData` entities when one `Image` can have multiple `ImageData` references.

Java classes look like this:

Image.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image", schema = "public")
@AttributeAccessor(value = "PROPERTY")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Image implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, precision=10)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="image_id_seq",sequenceName="image_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="image_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false, cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="default_image_data_id",nullable=false)
    @NotNull
    private ImageData defaultImageData;
```

ImageData.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image_data", schema = "public")
@AttributeAccessor(value = "PROPERTY")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ImageData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, precision=10)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="image_data_id_seq",sequenceName="image_data_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="image_data_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    @Length(max=255)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="image_id",nullable=false)
    private Image image;
```

Also I have a `Product` entity which can have `Image`

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false, cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="image_screenshot_id",nullable=false)
    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
```

When I want to create a Product entity I do:

```
product = new Product();
Image image = new Image();
image.setDefaultImageData(new ImageData());
product.setImage(image);

sessionFactory.getCurrentSesion().save(product);
```

But this fails with message:

> Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable
> association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient
> entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent
> entities.

I understand that having it 'circular' Image (defaultImageData) <> ImageData (image) might cause issues, but these two properties are important for me to easily determine default image.

Is there any option how to solve it while preserving both properties?

Comment: `I have an Image and ImageData entities when one Image can have multiple ImageData references.` And why for this case you use `@OneToOne` ?

Comment: because image can have only one defualtimage.

Comment: @michal-jakubeczy Do you mean `Image can have multiple ImageData references` and `Image have exactly one default ImageData` ? because the first sentence starts with one to many and then code only shows default image data reference

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai yes, Image can have only one default ImageData, but Image can have multiple 
 associated ImageData records (but only one default).

Comment: I reproduced your sample based the code you had in question and was able to save it. See my answer. If it doesn't work, Can you add the full class of `Image` to question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add the `mappedBy`

```
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, 
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,mappedBy = "image")
    @JoinColumn(name = "default_image_data_id", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private ImageData defaultImageData;
```

- And also `image` and `imageData` are in bi-directional relationship and you need to set both side

```
    product = new Product();
    Image image = new Image();
    ImageData imageData = new ImageData()
    image.setDefaultImageData(imageData);
    imageData.setImage(image)
    product.setImage(image);
```

- My Github repo

  https://github.com/kavi-kanap/stack-overflow-62752070

Comment: I tried your answer, seems I got a bit further, but now I get an error when I save product, saying: `ERROR: null value in column "default_image_data_id" violates not-null constraint` seems like it tries to save image entity first, but obviously image_data is not asved yet. Seems like this is hard to be solved as it cannot insert image_data without image and image without image_data.

Comment: Weirrd. I saved the product too and it worked. Are product and image bi-directional? because the code shows it as uni directional. Can you see if you can store the image with my code (without relating it to product)?

Comment: product and image are uni-directional. I am affraid it is not possible to even deal with this with raw SQL. Check in your example that default_image_data_id is not null.

Comment: I managed to deal with that when I made defaultImageData property NULLABLE. Not very DB friendly but this is the only way (you basically cannot insert two records which depend on each other). Anyway, your tip with mappedBy led me to the solution. In combination with information in comments I can pronounce this as an answer to my issue.

Comment: It would be good if you can compare my git repo with yours because I didn't make any relationship optional. I have updated my answer